# How to trigger two function in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi how to trigger function in c#. If i click save Button, data is stored to SQL and exit from code behind. After that send email function will trigger.  Can you give some example?

**I want to exit after job 1 is done.. But job 2 is continue in code behind. Because Send Email functionality take some time...**

//Coding is..

protected void DayPilot_EventMove(object sender, DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.EventMoveEventArgs e)
{

try

```
{ 

    //**Job 1:**
    DayPilotCalendarWeek.DataSource = Moving(e.Id);
    DayPilotCalendarWeek.DataBind();
    DayPilotCalendarWeek.Update();
    //**Job 2** 
    SendEmail();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

}

Comment: Learn about Delegates

Comment: Hi I saw some Example..  But I cant understand.. need clear Simple exmple

Comment: you can use new thread or delgate or worker therad for sending mail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Asynchronous two job in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016236/how-to-asynchronous-two-job-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Console

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TaskDoer td = new TaskDoer();
            td.doTask+=SomeTasks.StoreToSql;
            td.doTask+=SomeTasks.SendEmail;

            td.StartTasks(5);
        }
    }

// delegate

    public delegate void Do(object o);

// class which uses delegate

    public class TaskDoer
    {
        public event Do doTask;

        public void StartTasks(object o)
        {
            doTask(o);
        }
    }

// class which provides method definitions that could be used with the delegate

    public class SomeTasks
    {
        public static void StoreToSql(object o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Stored to SQL");
        }

        public static void SendEmail(object o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Email Sent");
        }
    }
```

Please note, there are better ways to do this. But since you are starting with delegate this will help you understand how it works, and what is available.

Comment: Confused this windows coding... My Coding is                             protected void DayPilotCalendarWeek_EventMove(object sender, DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.EventMoveEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CommonCls com = new CommonCls();
        //**Job 1:**
        DayPilotCalendarWeek.DataSource = Moving(e.Id, e.OldStart.ToString(), e.NewStart.ToString());
        DayPilotCalendarWeek.DataBind();
        DayPilotCalendarWeek.Update();
        //**Job 2** 
        SendEmail();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex.ToString());
    }
}

Comment: ok, to relate it to your original question, 1. Add "TaskDoer" and "SomeTasks" class, "Do" delegate in your solution. 2. Write your logic for storing to database in "StoreToSql" method, sending email in "SendEmail" method. Remove all Console.Writelines. 3. Everything written inside static void main, move it to your Button's click event handler.

Comment: Please answer like button click event...  I want to exit after job 1 is done.. But job 2 is continue in code behind. Because Send Email functionality take some time...

Comment: hmm, you need asynchronous functionality. let me modify my answer

Comment: hi Please Update your answer ..\

Comment: Go through this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h80ttd5f(v=vs.110).aspx. meanwhile ill update my answer